# Facebook Slider: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, facebook

I've had a website with unchanged code running and suiting my clients needs for years now. I probably should be updating it sometime soon since it's been around since the ice age. The page is using a slider plugin called TN3 Gallery. Accessing Facebook image galleries by their ID (ie. 10150593562656862).

However, I made a modification the other day and after the files were uploaded a jquery slider I have connected to facebook quit working out of nowhere! I never changed this code, re-uploaded the dependencies, updated dependencies, rolled back dependencies, etc.

It seems Facebook has done a forced migration to their Graph API v2.0:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_login
http://techcrunch.com/2015/04/28/facebook-api-shut-down/#.7bznhf:Xb2n

**Console Log:**

*With 1.4.2*

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>
> c.extend.each @   jquery-1.4.2.min.js:29
>
> h.facebook.parsePhotos    @   tn3.facebook.min.js:12
>
> h.facebook.request.f.ajax.success @   tn3.facebook.min.js:12
>
> b @   jquery-1.4.2.min.js:124
>
> c.extend.ajax.A.(anonymous function)  @   jquery-1.4.2.min.js:125
>   (anonymous
>   function) @   photos?callback=jsonp1435211307395&_=1435211307471&offset=0&limit=20&fields=id%2Cpicture%2Csource%2…:1

ALSO

*With 1.7.1*

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>
> e.extend.each @ jquery-1.7.1.min.js:2h.facebook.parsePhotos @
>   tn3.facebook.min.js:12
>
> h.facebook.request.f.ajax.success @ tn3.facebook.min.js:12
>
> f.Callbacks.n @ jquery-1.7.1.min.js:2
>
> f.Callbacks.o.fireWith @ jquery-1.7.1.min.js:2
>
> w @
>   jquery-1.7.1.min.js:4f.ajaxTransport.send.d.onload.d.onreadystatechange
>   @ jquery-1.7.1.min.js:4

**script**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var tn1 = $('.mygallery').tn3({  
                skinDir:"skins",
        skin:"tn3a",
            autoplay:true,
            delay:4500,
            mouseWheel:false,           
        image:{
            crop:true,
            random:true,
            maxZoom:3.0

        },          
        external:[{
        origin:"facebook",
        source:"album",
        ID:"10150593562656862"          
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I was using the slider called TN3 Gallery. It was the only gallery I found a long time ago that flawlessy pulled gallery specific images from facebook pages without the need for creating an app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea what plugin you are using there, and how it tries to fetch data from Facebook – but it probably gets tripped up by the recent migration to Facebook Graph API v2.

With that, now almost all API requests (except for user profile pictures) **require** the use of an *access token* – and since you likely did not provide one so far, the API request will now result in an error only, and give you no actual data at all.

That means, first of all you will need to use a Facebook app – don’t know if you were using one already, but if not you will have to create one.

And then, if you want to do this purely client-side, you will have to make users log in to your app first, so that you can get a user access token for them to use with the request.

Your alternative is do fetch the data server-side (and then deliver it to the client from there). That way, you could use your app access token, and thereby eliminate the need for anyone to log in. (Please be aware that the app access token does **never** belong in client-side code, so don’t even think about using it in your JavaScript. That would create quite a security vulnerability for your app.)

Answer (score 0):

Due to the recent changes in the Facebook API the plugin tn3 gallery no longer works with Facebook to fetch images from a gallery or user.

It was purely coincidental that the change took effect the same night that I saved an content update to the page which seemed to be causal in nature to begin with.

The developers of the plugin have provided no resolution or expectations as to when they will have it functional again. They also offer the ability to work with Flickr galleries but this doesn't work either due to flickr's requirement to traffic requests over https:// I had to revert to local content changes in the end to get it working.